# StandardSQL - how to do a LOOKUP in a table without matching columns

Tags: google-bigquery

Wondering if I could get some help with this.

I have 2 tables.
Table `hosts`, has 2 columns, `hostname` and `ipv4_address`
Table `netblocks`, has 2 columns, `netblock` and `building`

I want a resulting table with 2 columns, `hostname` and `building`

I have available a function `IP_IN_NET` that returns `true` if the `ipv4_address` is in the `netblock`.

So far I've done a crossjoin, by doing `FROM hosts,netblocks`, but that ends up with a huge table, as it has as many rows as the multiple of those 2 tables.

What's the proper way of doing something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your function `IP_IN_NET`? It's hard to give you a proper example without that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach if you could work with arrays.

provides an array of the matched buildings for each hostname.

```
SELECT 
  hostname,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    DISTINCT
    IF(IP_IN_NET(ipv4_address, netblock), building, NULL)
    IGNORE NULL
  ) AS buildings
FROM hosts, netblock
GROUP BY hostname
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in your first approach you will get the following error message: "Subquery in join predicate should only depend on exactly one join side"

Comment: I agree with you. I suspect that as well. so I included the 2nd approach.

Comment: Actually, I tried it and I get that error message. So, I confirm that approach 1 won't work. The explanation can be found on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54882205/5521575

Comment: Thank you. I will update my answer to only about approach 2.

Comment: This is computationally expensive compared to having a CTE. For example if `IPV4` is non unique in the `hosts` table, you end up looking up `netblock` multiple times. With a CTE though you could precompute `IPV4` to `netblock` mapping and then join it with `hosts` table

Comment: Fremzy, we would like to know more about your solution. Could you post an answer?